# Upgrade from Ubuntu server 16.04 to 18.04 fails

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

When attempting to upgrade, I get the following message:

```
W:The repository
'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid Release' does not have a Release file.,
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.,
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.,
E:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/partner/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80],
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: The `vivid` bit is pointing to a Vivid Vervet (15.04) repository, which would be long gone by now as it’s well out of support. You will need to find the record in your sources list and comment it out. It may still be an uphill battle to upgrade from 16.04, though, as that release has been out of support for 4+ months … 

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 16.04?   Why would a you have a *vivid* line there? as that was two *release-upgrades* before *xenial* or 16.04.  Your issue maybe you're not running 16.04, and 15.04 puts you in a very different situation. An upgrade via re-install makes more sense from 15.04 (but I'd consider starting again with a *clean* install as the system doesn't *feel* used or important to be ignored that long)

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has passed its End-of-life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @waltinator upgrading from EOL version to a supported version is a valid question in Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It may be easier to perform a fresh install of the latest LTS, 20.04

Comment: You have to remove the single problematic line about *vivid* from your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then install all updates to current system and then proceed with upgrade.

Comment: NOrbert,  that did it.   The upgrade is in progress.   There were three lines related to "vivid" that I commented out.   THANKS!!   It would take me hours to describe how I got into this situation.   I hope this also corrects my problem with the Ubuntu 16.04 server from hanging.  And, WakeOnLan from not working,  And, not being able to upgrade Oracle VirtualBox.   And, why it sometimes boots into my backup partition.  I am still looking for how to determine which APS have been added in the last 3+ years on this HP Envy Phoenix tower.

Comment: Good and BAD news.  The first attempt hung about 50 minutes into the update.  The second attempt ran to completion without hanging.  The Oracle VirtualBox partition is there.  But no startup procedure.

Comment: Too bad you didn't mention your problems with "hanging" and with WOL and VirtualBox and Boot selection and APS in your original question. I suspect that would have changed much of the advice that you received. My advice: You have too many old, weird problems to make your current server worth fixing. Backup your data, clean-install Ubuntu Server 20.04, and then rebuild each service.